# PSQLException: ERROR: column does not exist Position: 8

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, postgresql-9.1

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "feedbackid" does not exist
>   Position: 8

I am getting this error but unable to understand what the reason behind this.
It shows:-
**

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "feedbackid" does not
>   exist   Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column
>   "feedback.feedbackId".   Position: 8

**

Database table in postgres:

```
create table `company`.`feedback` (
```

`feedbackId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `feedbackActionId` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feedbackText` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `createdDate` date NOT NULL
);

[image: database table in postgres]

```
public Feedback getFeedbackById(int id) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    conn = DBConnection.setDBConnection();
    String sqlQuery = "select feedbackId, feedbackActionId, description, feedbackText, email, createdDate" +
                           "from feedback " + 
                           " where feedbackId = " + id ;
    DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection();
    ResultSet resultSet = dbConn.getResultSet(sqlQuery, conn);
    int feedbackId = resultSet.getInt("feedbackId");
    int feedbackActionId = resultSet.getInt("feedbackActionId");
    String description = resultSet.getString("description");
    String feedbackText = resultSet.getString("feedbackText");
    String email = resultSet.getString("email");
    Date createdDate = resultSet.getDate("createdDate");
    feedback = new Feedback(feedbackId, feedbackActionId, description, feedbackText, email, createdDate);

    resultSet.close();

    return feedback;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include your feedback table schema in your question?

Comment: A space is missing after the column names

Comment: change "from feedback " to " from feedback "

Comment: @RaviChandra thanks. but after removing space i am getting still same error.

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "feedbackid" does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "feedback.feedbackId".
  Position: 8

Answer (score 0):

This question might help you. Looks like Postgres is case senstive towards column names. You might need to include field name in quotes. [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive)

Comment: @AnshuAshish Please accept this as answer or upvote, if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to use:
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
in your POJO class Id Field.
This thing solved my error.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes occurs when you use double quotes instead of single quotes for strings
replace where `user_id="random_id"` with where `user_id='random_id'`